# Creating a subset of a data frame with specific years

Tags: r, dataframe, subset

I am using a data frame from WDI and am attempting to clean a merged dataset.

One of the two merged datasets only has values at 2000,2005,2010, and so I would like to have a subsetted data frame that only includes those years (for each country etc).

My code is as follows:

`WB_Merge1 = subset(WB_Merge, select = c(year==2000 | year==2005 | year==2010))`

However, when I run it in R it creates a data frame that now has all 5502 observations but no variables?

Could anyone help? Many thanks.

Comment: See the posts up top for how to do this generally. In your specific case, it seems like you misread the `subset` docs: "select: expression, indicating columns to select from a data frame."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just used the wrong argument, to select rows you want `subset=`.

```
subset(dat, subset=c(year == 2000 | year == 2005 | year == 2010))
```

Or more concise:

```
subset(dat, subset=year %in% c(2000, 2005, 2010))
#    year          x          z
# 1  2000 -0.4703161 0.62147778
# 6  2005 -0.6667708 0.03479132
# 11 2010 -0.8059292 0.43732005
```

`select=` is for the columns.

```
subset(dat, subset=year %in% c(2000, 2005, 2010), select=c(year, z))
#    year          z
# 1  2000 0.62147778
# 6  2005 0.03479132
# 11 2010 0.43732005
```

Note, that if you provide the arguments in the right order, you may leave out the argument names and just do:

```
subset(dat, year %in% c(2000, 2005, 2010), c(year, z))
```

---

*Data:*

```
set.seed(42)
dat <- data.frame(year=2000:2022, x=rnorm(23), z=runif(23))
```

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
require(dplyr)
WB_Merge1 <- filter(WB_Merge, year %in% c(2000, 2005, 2010)
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution with `which()`

Sample data:

```
set.seed(42)
data <- data.frame(year=2000:2022, x=rnorm(23), z=runif(23))
```

Sample code:

```
new.data <- data[ which( data$year == 2000 | data$year == 2005 | data$year == 2010) , ]
```

Output:

```
   year          x         z
1  2000  1.3709584 0.8877549
6  2005 -0.1061245 0.3467482
11 2010  1.3048697 0.6772768
```